# Show Google Interstitial Ad after Button Click on WebView site

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I made a WebView application with my site for generating images. Also i added in Android Studio Google AdMob ad (banner and interstitial) with banner everything is fine and interstitial ad opens on application start as i put it in onCreate (i don't know other options) but i would like to make interstitial ad pop up after 10-20 clicks on the generate button, the problem is that it is on the site in a WebView and I am very weak in programming, please help, I have been struggling with this issue for a long time ,_, Any suggestions are welcome thanks.

My code: (Sorry for the dirt, I'm very noob at this)

```
import...
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://waifulab.pics/");
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                loadInterstitialAd();
            }

            BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };
        });
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Interstitial Ad
        loadInterstitialAd();
    }
    public void loadInterstitialAd() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-3963094388976940/6550490464", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        interstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                        interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(@NonNull AdError adError) {
                                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to show Ad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Shown Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Dismissed / Closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                            @Override
                            public void onAdImpression() {
                                super.onAdImpression();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Impression Count", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdClicked() {
                                super.onAdClicked();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ad Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to Load Ad because=" + loadAdError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack())
            webView.goBack();
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.create();
            dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
            dialog.setMessage("Do you want to exit?");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { finish();
                }
            });
            dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.cancel();
                    loadInterstitialAd();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

My last question couldn't get an answer but I really need to do it T_T

I reviewed a lot of videos and publications, it seems to me that (WebView.addJavascriptInterface) would help me, but I could not figure it out.